# Concatenate two output layers of same dimension

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, concatenation

I have two hidden layers of dimension 50 from 2 different autoencoder models. The shape is `[None,50]` for both of them. But when executing the following code:

```
concat_layer = Concatenate()([_1.layers[7], _2.layers[11]])
softmax_layer = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(concat_layer)
sum_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[_1_x_train, _2_x_train], outputs=softmax_layer)
sum_model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='mse')
```

I get the Error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` for `Concatenate()([_1.layers[7], _2.layers[11]])`

Edit: Here is the layer structure of the two models.

_1 summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 500)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 250)               125250    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 250)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               25100     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 50)                5050      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2550      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 100)               5100      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 250)               25250     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 500)               125500    
=================================================================
```

_2 summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 24765)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 5000)              123830000 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 5000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2500)              12502500  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 2500)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1000)              2501000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1000)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 500)               500500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 250)               125250    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 100)               25100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 50)                5050      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2550      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 100)               5100      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 250)               25250     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 500)               125500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 1000)              501000    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 2500)              2502500   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 5000)              12505000  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 24765)             123849765 
=================================================================
```

I have to add something here because otherwise the changes will not be accepted because its only 'code' i added.

Comment: @Kaveh When I use `.output` I get the following error for the line `sum_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[_1_x_train, _2_x_train], outputs=softmax_layer)`: `ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from tf.keras.Input`
`

Comment: @Kaveh _1_x_train: 500 dimensional vector, _2_x_train: 24765 dimensional vector. I got this information about the error: `Received: [[ 0.12298707 -0.02646363 -0.00148154 ... -0.13103688 -0.08349749
  -0.02245508]
 ...
 [ 0.04945283  0.07689854  0.09487517 ... -0.10219    -0.03503933
  -0.05549472]] (missing previous layer metadata).
`(I removed some values because there are just too much for this comment section)

Comment: @Kaveh Thank you, that makes sense. However, I still get the following error: `ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from tf.keras.Input. Received: <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x7f61a67a8da0> (missing previous layer metadata)`. I changed the Model to `sum_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[_1.layers[0], _2.layers[0]], outputs=softmax_layer)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates, it is trying to get subscript (`object[index]`) of an object which is `NoneType`.

The input to a`tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()` layer should be a tensor. But you have passed layer instances. So instead of passing layers, pass their output like this:

```
concat_layer = Concatenate()([_1.layers[7].output, _2.layers[11].output])
```

In addition, your model definition should change, since you have passed input data as inputs, instead of the first layers. Get the models input layer by `model.input`. So modified code should be like this:

```
#sum_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[_1_x_train, _2_x_train], outputs=softmax_layer)
sum_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[_1.input, _2.input], outputs=softmax_layer)
```

You should pass input data to `model.fit()`.